# iOS 7 Jailbreak, iPhone 5S question

Tags: jailbreak, cydia, iphone

So I have the 5S and the iOS 7 Jailbreak came out the other day. See one problem though is that mobile substrate and preferenceloader don't quite work with any 64-bit devices. Anyway, the whole point of the question is if anyone knows any information on excatly when those two very important Cydia packages will be optimized for the 5S/Any other 64-bit devices.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't expect a patch anytime soon. If you read the twitter strem of @saurik you will see that the author of substrate wasn't given time to work with the team that released the jailbreak and that there are at best - strained relations and differing motives and at worst, possibly a disengagement of iOS 7 patches for some time.

https://twitter.com/saurik/status/414743665362231296

Read through the posts up to 24 dec for more of the back story of what doesn't work and why.

Answer (score 0):

Already updated, works for all 64-bit devices. Have fun with your new jailbroken devices!